# How to compare enum value to scanner input in java for switch statement

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

Im' trying to get user input if he presses "a", he can do the average, calls in average method if he types in "s", he uses the sum method.

Im new to enums so im experimenting. I made an enum that stores a,b and am trying to compare it's values to user input using scanner.

I could be using if statements and forget the whole enum thing but i want to know how it works.
thanks.

```
public enum RecursionEnum {

 s, a

}
```

main class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Recursion {

static RecursionEnum enumtest;

public static void yn() {
    Scanner boges = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a for average or s for  sum");
    String answer = boges.nextLine();

    switch (enumtest) {

    case a:
        average();
    case s:
        sums();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    yn();

}

public static int sums() {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    int sum = i + j;
    return sum;
}

public static double average() {

    Scanner avgs = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter total number of numbers; ");
    double tnum = avgs.nextDouble();
    double[] nums = new double[(int) tnum];
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tnum; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter number " + (i + 1) + " : ");
        nums[i] = avgs.nextDouble();
        sum += nums[i];

    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    double avg = sum / tnum;

    return avg;

}

}
```

This is the output:

```
Enter a for average or s for  sum
a
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.towerdef.shit.Recursion.yn(Recursion.java:14)
 at com.towerdef.shit.Recursion.main(Recursion.java:26)
```

Answer (score 0):

Enumerable types have a synthetic static method, namely `valueOf(String)`, which will return an enum instance matching the input, if it exists. Note that the input is case-sensitive in this case. Trim is used to deal with potential extraneous whitespace.

You can switch on that:

```
public static void yn() {
    Scanner boges = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a for average or s for  sum");
    String answer = boges.nextLine();

switch (RecursionEnum.valueOf(answer.trim())) {

case a:
    average();
case s:
    sums();
}

}
```

Of course, on Java 7 and higher, you can switching on strings. You may thus use:

```
public static void yn() {
    Scanner boges = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a for average or s for  sum");
    String answer = boges.nextLine();

switch (answer.trim()) {

case "a":
    average();
    break;
case "s":
    sums();
    break;
}

}
```

Comment: the [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) here is coded the same way the asker had done. Is it sameor i'm missing out something? @hexafraction

Comment: @maxx777 I don't understand your question, what is the same? Edit: Found it. He doesn't assign to the variable used in the switch statement

Comment: Wow this valueOf method works like a charm. Didn't know it existed or how it would be used. I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: @hexafraction oh yes, thank. i missed such simple thing :| . So i think if he adds an assignment statement before switch, the code would be fine.